# jsp file not applying styles of linked css files

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, model-view-controller

I am using a controller to serve my index.jsp page.

When I type: `http://localhost:8080/Driving-Instructor-Gary/HomeController?page=home`

It loads the index.jsp file fine using this code:

```
package uk.co.morleys;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HomeController
 */
@WebServlet("/HomeController")
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HomeController() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String page = request.getParameter("page");
        String views = "/WEB-INF/views/";
        switch (page){
        case "home":
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(views + "index.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the css styling is not being applied to the webpage.

Here is the css file linking in index.jsp document:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Morley's Motoring Mentoring</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Mepham">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Here is the file structure of the project:

[image]

Why is the styling not being applied?

Answer (score 2):

Your css styles are located within the WEB-INF folder. This folder is not accessible for the user / browser when the app has been deployed.
Try to pull the folder(s) (also img, js) up into WebContent. And change the path in your jsp file accordingly.

Furthermore you should use standard jstl taglib. Use c:url to get the right (deployment) path if your application will not run in root context.